# How to make optional word in regex

Tags: python, regex

I have this sample data

```
/user/test/30173650
/sample/30079887?pos=0&code=3232323&cc=32232
/sample/30079887?pos=1
/test/codemelbourne/30173650/dsadsad/dasdasdsa/dasdas
```

I want to get the number item.

I have this code:

```
\/(\d*)[?]?
```

Why does this also match `/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the remaining part of your regex also matches the empty string:

- `\d*` - **zero** or more digits
- `[?]?` - an **optional** questionmark

To fix this, you can use repetition that requires at least one digit to be found:

```
\/(\d+)[?]?
```

Answer (score 1):

`*` Means that it will get **zero** or more digits. `+`means **one** or more, so this will remove all empty matches.

[Working regex](https://regex101.com/r/tD2aF9/2) `\/(\d+)[?]?`

`()` is the capture group so this will only return the digit needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `*` which means, 0 or more digits. Use `+`:

```
\/(\d+)\??
```